# Detect peak black pixel in an image (Android)?

Tags: android, loops, signal-processing

I am currently working on ECG graph analysis and in order make things easier, I think detecting peaks and calculating the distance of peak-to-peak might be of big help. How can I detect the first/peak black pixel in an image?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution how you can do this

```
boolean pf=false,qf=false,rf=false,sf=false,tf=false;
    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapFatoryOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapFatoryOptions.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test4,bitmapFatoryOptions);
    bmp = bmp.copy(bmp.getConfig(), true);
    int thresh = 150;
    for(int i=0;i<bmp.getWidth();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<bmp.getHeight();j++){
            int pixel = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
            int red = Color.green(pixel);
            int green = Color.red(pixel);
            int blue = Color.blue(pixel);
            if(red<thresh&&green<thresh&&blue<thresh){
                if((oldj>=j||p.x==0)&&!pf){
                    p.x=i;
                    p.y=j;

                }
                else{
                    pf=true;
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "told="+oldj, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(pf&&!qf&&(oldj<=j||q.x==0)){
                    q.x=i;
                    q.y=j;
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "old="+oldj, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    qf=true;
                    if(!rf&&(oldj>=j||r.x==0)){
                        r.x=i;
                        r.y=j;
                    }
                    else{
                        rf=true;
                        if(!sf&&(oldj<=j||s.x==0)){
                            s.x=i;
                            s.y=j;
                        }
                        else{
                            sf=true;
                            if(!tf&&(oldj>=j||t.x==0)){
                                t.x=i;
                                t.y=j;
                            }
                            else{
                                tf=true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
                oldj=j;
                oldi=i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    paint(p,bmp);
    paint(q,bmp);
    paint(r,bmp);
    paint(s,bmp);
    paint(t,bmp);

}
```